# Difference between string operators + and << in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and to this site.

The following two functions are different, one alters the variable outside the function and one does not.

```
def m1 (x)
  x << "4"
end

def m2 (x)
  x = x + "4"
end


str="123"

m2(str)   #str remains unchanged 123

m1(str)   #str is changed to 1234
```

I would like to make sure I understand this correctly -

When m1 is called, the reference to str is copied and passed to the function which sees it as x.  Operator << changes x which references the origial str so str is changed by this operation.

When m2 is called, the reference to str is copied and passed to the function which sees it as x.  Operator + creates a new string, and the assignment x = x + "4" simply redirects x to the new string leaving the original str variable untouched.

Right?

Thanks

[image: method declarations and invokation]

Comment: `m2(str)` should return `"1234"`, then `m1(str)` should return `"1234"` and after that `str` will equal `"1234"`. Are you sure about your results?

Comment: i'm using `Ruby 1.9.3p392` and it works in my case. put `puts` before those methods and check.

Comment: @tmpmember what do you mean "it works" in your case?

Comment: that strings change in both cases to 1234

Comment: @pferdefleisch I think OP didn't edit his post properly. But his intention is - after calling `m1(str)` `str` has changed as well. which should be. But after call `m2(str)` output comes as `1234` but `str` has remains same `123`. which is also correct as per the document.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu That's what I imagined. "Are you sure..." from my first comment should have been worded differently.

Comment: @Jonathan If you have understood,then please accept the answer whichever you think to proper.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 6.9.1, which is probably using a very old build of Ruby, and m2 doesn't change str.

Comment: i posted a screenshot of it

Comment: That's Photoshopped! ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> > [`String#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-2B) :: `str + other_str → new_str` Concatenation—Returns a new String containing `other_str` concatenated to `str`.
> >
> > [`String#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) :: `str << integer → str` : Append—Concatenates the given object to `str`.

`<<` doesn't create the new object, where as `+` does.

```
a = "str"
#=> "str"
a.object_id
#=> 14469636
b = a << "ing"
#=> "string"
a.object_id
#=> 14469636
b.object_id
#=> 14469636

a=  "str"
#=> "str"
b = a + "ing"
#=> "string"
a.object_id
#=> 16666584
b.object_id
#=> 17528916
```

***EDIT***

From your comment, got your point. See below:

```
def m1 (x)
 x << "4"
end
#=> nil
def m2 (x)
 x = x + "4"
end
#=> nil

str="123"
#=> "123"

m2(str)
#=> "1234"

str
#=> "123"
```

Here `str` didn't change as you passed the value inside the method `m2()`, all the changes local to the method as per the above call. Thus below `str` not showing that change.To see the change you have to call it as below.

```
str = m2(str)
#=> "1234"

str
#=> "1234"
```

**OR**

You could do the stuff as below :- where I passed reference address of `str` but not the value.

```
str = "abc"
#=> "abc"
str.object_id
#=> 16250484
ObjectSpace._id2ref(16250484)
#=> "abc"
def m1 (x)
ObjectSpace._id2ref(x) << "4"
end
#=> nil
m1(16250484)
#=> "abc4"
str
#=> "abc4"
```

Hope it make sense :)

Cheers!

Comment: See my `EDIT`, Hope that helps.

Comment: yes thank you very much, the this seemingly "innocent" code example actually has a lot behind it as you've helped me see :)

Comment: yup, another example of how much there is to learn in ruby. it's an interesting language

Answer (score 2):

`<<` the concatenate operator is destructive to a string. This means that it will manipulate the variable it acts upon, not just return the result of the expression.

example:

```
str = "abc"
puts str + "d" # "abcd"

puts str # "abc"

puts str << "d" # "abcd"

puts str # "abcd"
```

Answer (score 1):

> The following two functions are different, one alters the variable outside the function and one does not.

This is wrong. *Neither* of the two methods (they are methods, BTW, not functions, Ruby doesn't have functions; there is a fundamental difference) alters the `str` variable. `m1` modifies the object the variable *points to*, but that is completely different from modifying the variable *itself*.

Comment: yes you are right, this is something i have come to understand only later