# Difference between << and =

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain why `foo` is mutated in version 1? What is the difference between `<<` and `=` assignment?

VERSION 1

```
foo = "apple"
bar = foo
"foo: #{foo}"    # => foo: apple

bar << "hello"
"bar: #{bar}"    # => bar: applehello
"foo: #{foo}"    # => foo: applehello
```

VERSION2

```
foo = "apple"
bar = foo    
"foo: #{foo}"    # => foo: apple

bar  = bar + "hello"
"bar: #{bar}"    # => bar: applehello
"foo: #{foo}"    # => foo: apple
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between string operators + and << in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461966/difference-between-string-operators-and-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `=` is an assignment as you said.
But `<<` is not an assignment - it's concatenation operator when the left operand is a string.
So:

```
bar  = bar + "hello"
```

creates a new string by joining contents of `bar` with "hello" and then this **new string** is assigned to variable `bar`, while:

```
bar << "hello"
```

does the in-place concatenation of string - `bar` won't be set to new string but the string it holds will be modified.

So with `<<` bar and foo still keep reference to the same object while with `=` only bar gets a new value.

Comment: so for << operation, ruby will look for bar's reference, which is foo and then look for the string "apple" that is referenced by foo? and do concatenation?

Comment: @KitHo both, `bar` and `foo` reference the same object, it's not a chain of pointers

Comment: Almost. But you're on a good path. When accessing `bar` there's no need to look for `foo` because both variables reference the same object. So modifying this object with `<<` affects both `foo` and `bar` because it's still the same object. With `=` you say "I want `bar` to reference other object from now on".

Comment: @elmo, i think bar is referencing the address of foo, which is referencing "apple", am i correct?

Comment: @KitHo no! Both `foo` and `bar` are referencing object of type `string` with value "apple". This is one object and there is no concept of address here. Both `foo` and `bar` have direct access to the underlying object. `foo` is not better than `bar` in any way.

Comment: @KitHo example: `foo = "apple"; bar = foo; foo = "orange"` afterwards, `bar` still references `"apple"`

Comment: out of interest, does anyone know which is quicker / more efficient? Obviously I recognise the difference between mutation and creation of a new object so there are some situations in which one would not want to blindly do "the more efficient one".

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `bar` as a reference to `foo`. The `<<` operator works in place, as in the first version, and in the second version you're using `+` which produces a new value, while not changing the original.

Answer (score 0):

`bar << "hello"` appends to `bar` (which is `foo`), while `bar  = bar + "hello"` creates a copy of the string, `foo` remains untouched.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation with `+` returns a new object:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-2B

The append operator acts on the object that the reference points to:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C

In the first example you are appending to the object that both foo and bar point to.

In the second example you are adding "hello" to the object that bar points to which returns a new object which, in turn, bar now points to all the while foo still points to the object whose value is still just "apple"

Answer (score 0):

First observe the following:--

```
str = "test"
#=> "test"
str[1]
#=> "e"
str1 = str
#=> "test"
str.object_id 
#=> 8509820
str1.object_id
#=> 8509820
```

So string is stored as an array of each character in Ruby. Other language like Java also returns complete string if you just use char type reference. Similarly here also we get each char of second string added to array of characters for first string.

```
str << "string"
#=> "teststring"
str1
#=> "teststring"
str.object_id
#=> 8509820
str1.object_id
#=> 8509820
```

Here no new object gets created. Same array holds each characters of second string.

Now observe the following:--

```
str = "test"
#=> "test"
str1 = str
str.object_id
#=> 9812345
str1.object_id
#=> 9812345

str = str + "string"
#=> "teststring"
str.object_id
#=> 9901234
str1
#=> "test"
str1.object_id
#=> 9812345
```

Here we see `+` operator causes creation of a new object.